# 2 targets with ColumnDef different properties - Datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables-1.10

How could one do ColumnDef for two targets with different properties for each?

i.e.

```
columnDefs: [{         // for first column
              targets: 0,
              visable: false,
            }],

columnDefs: [{        // for last column
              targets -1,
              className: 'last',
              data: null,
              orderable: false
            }]
```

I have the row ID as the first column, which the user doesn't need to see, but the data has to be there to be sent to a "upadate.php", to update a MySQL table. The last column contains actions to edit the row.

It's not the end of the world if this simply isn't possible, as the end user is trusted with this information. This is simply to prevent an accidental change in the row ID.

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled upon a workaround on how to do this. The code goes like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            columnDefs: [ {
            targets: -1,
            data: null,
            defaultContent: "<div style='text-align:center'><a class='btn btn-default'><i class='fa fa-search'></i></a> <a class='btn btn-default'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></a> <a class='btn btn-default'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></a></div>"
        },
        {
            targets: 4,
            orderable: false
        } ]
        });
    });
```

See the columnDefs section. I targeted the last column and the second part is i targeted a specific column.